# Trouble understanding where to put exchanges/comparisons counters in heapsort

Tags: java, algorithm, heapsort

Heapsort should be such that BuildHeap is O(n) and Heapify O(logN), right?
Overall efficiency O(NLogN)?

But no matter where I've been placing my counters, for an array of 2000 elements I get around 35,000-50,000 comparisons+exchanges.

My code, I call buildheap and then run heapSort with the built array 
(I get around 37,000 comparisons and 20000 exchanges) :

```
public class Sort {
 static int exchanges = 0;
  static int comparisons = 0;


public static void heapSort(int[] array)

{
  int size = 2000;

   for (int i = 2000; i >= 1; i--)
   {
 exchanges++;
    int temp = array[0];
   array[0] = array[i-1];
   array[i-1] = temp;
   size--;  
   heapify(array, 0, size);
    }
System.out.println("Number of exchanges is: " + exchanges);
System.out.println("Number of comparisons is: " + comparisons);
}   



public static int[] buildHeap(int[] array)
{
int N = 2000; //size of array
for (int index = (N/2); index >= 0; index--) 
   {
    heapify(array, index, N);

    }
return array;
}


public static void heapify(int[] array, int currentIndex, int N)
{
  int leftChild = (2*currentIndex) + 1;
int rightChild = (2*currentIndex)+ 2;
int largest = currentIndex; //just so it's assigned a value at first

if (leftChild <= N-1)
{
   comparisons++;
    if ((array[leftChild]) > (array[currentIndex]))
    {
        largest = leftChild; 
    }
}
else 
{
    largest = currentIndex;
}

if (rightChild <= N-1)
{
    comparisons++;
    if ((array[rightChild]) > (array[largest]))
    {
        largest = rightChild;
    }
}

if (largest != currentIndex)
{
    exchanges++;
    int temp = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[largest];
    array[largest] = temp;
    heapify(array, largest, N);
}

  }
 }
```

Comment: Please update code with counters and add test case.

Comment: @iNan ok, just did.

Comment: Number of exchanges is: 8743
Number of comparisons is: 16363 result I got using random array. Number of comparisions is nlogn which is correct here

Comment: `2000*log₂(2000)` is 21932 so the exchanges seem about right.

Comment: @user3386109 wow, just realized i'd been doing my calculations in base 10...   thanks So exchanges seem right, but why do I have so many comparisons?

Comment: @iNan, using this code with a random array yielded those numbers? Not sure why mine don't math that.

Comment: Because you compare left and right, and then possibly exchange once. So roughly twice as many compares.

Comment: Sorry, but how else would it be done if not comparing left and right?

Comment: I didn't say that you shouldn't compare left and right. I said you have twice as many comparisons as exchanges. That's to be expected and doesn't change the fact that the time is O(nlogn). Big-O ignores constants.

Comment: I recall the constant being either 1.5 or 2? If we were to take into account the constant, my data would still be too high though, I think. I'm just trying to figure out why this is.

Comment: Ah, ok I realize now. Thanks for the comments/help.